# Why TypeScript doesn't enforce interface signature?

Tags: typescript

So, I've the following interface:

```js
interface DoStuffInterface {
    doStuff(value: string | number): string | number;
}
```

Why when implementing this interface TS doesn't enforce the signature?

```js
class NumberStuff implements DoStuffInterface {
    public doStuff(value: number): string | number { // <====== missing: | string
        return value;
    }
}

class StringStuff implements DoStuffInterface {
    public doStuff(value: string): string | number { // <====== missing: | number
        return value.toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

This is easily breakable with something like this:

```js
var numberStuff = new NumberStuff();
var stringStuff = new StringStuff();

function run(thing: DoStuffInterface): void {
    console.log(thing.doStuff(42));
}

run(numberStuff);
run(stringStuff); // <====== this fails, due to: `42.toLowerCase()`
```

So, why TS doesn't enforce `NumberStuff` & `StringStuff` to have the proper signature? If the signature was properly set this would be a compile-time error, instead you get a run-time error.

Am I missing some config flag? Or is it expected behaviour?

[Here the full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDKYCuMYCS408SyA3gFDI3IAmWu+AFAG5wA2OEAXMgM5gooAObIAPshA4AtgCNoASj6DhIMZOnzoAbkoBfSpQQc4-fsgByshVGx4YyYDIAOHCDIjgLGe-iKQsIgoVLTILjhyHMAI9IwObJzcfFq2ygJCohJSNtAUyAD0BcgAPAC8FZXIMsDmonySqqLUYbRQELhQIMjsXBB6YYaGxqbmyNhqIn6Ozm4eXmA+8f7EQWShtBFRMXHTiX0qmerpTerZqXnkhcXllRXVtfz157lQLa3I7Z3dvdwAdGB0AAZdAAd2gAGEzBBmIoBrQhkYEOgQIIcto7ExHGUpBBQVZXns4cYUWjTlMscgcSA8eMjhSEsTKDAcCAEGBgCjPqzmGAABbPXxYgIkYLpVjoYB0CjvZDI1Hodx-DjoES8gXqP4MPYAFgATIpicMoDyLpiHMSTSBmOTpnDrqU7vd+bVkPBgBx+AAaejcZCAvgAA31AOBYMh0NhgaAA)

Comment: Just ot expand on your question, this errors on compilation: `type doStuff = (value: string | number) => string | number;

const doNumberStuff: doStuff = (value: number) => value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR to enable the desired behavior change method to property:

```
interface DoStuffInterface {
    doStuff: (value: string | number) => string | number;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIHsDKYCuMYCS408SyA3gFDI3IAmWu+AXMgBQBucANjhKwGcwUUAHNkAH2QgcAWwBG0AJTIAvAD5kQkSHFSZC6AG5KAX0qUE3OAIHIAcnMVRseGMmCyADtwiyI4HYYrvhEkLCIKFS0yF448tzACPSMbpw8fKwGzkqCwmKS0k7QFMgA9GXIADyqtXXIssC2YqxS2mLUMbRQELhQIMhcvBAmMebmlta2yNg6oiHunj5+AWBBqaHEEWTRtHEJSSkL6cN5c7la+bqF2SXk5ZU1dbUNTQItN8VQnV3IPX0DIZ8AB0YHQABl0AB3aAAYRsEDYSlGtHGQA)

---

For interfaces under [strictFunctionTypes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types) function type parameter positions are checked contravariantly (for "function prop") instead of bivariantly (for method)

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in **method** or constructor declarations. **Methods** are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as `Array<T>`) continue to mostly relate covariantly.